# Unable to install Swagger 6.2.3 for dotnet 6.0

Tags: .net-6.0

Am unable to resolve nuget error in a new webapi project on one of my laptop, but works good on another. Both have same VS Code, nuget, dotnet core versions and have the same project files

*error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (>= 6.2.3)' for 'net6.0'.*

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check if NuGet sources are available via `dotnet nuget list source`.

Add it, if missing, via:

```
dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source